# WebGL using raw data slower than js Image()

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, webgl

We are writing a web client to stream video, one type of stream uses a proprietary library, so we cannot use current plugins or HTML tags that support standard urls.
I have several years experience with OpenGL, so I decided to try out WebGL for rendering raw data frames.

Rendering using a js Image() that loads png files is extremely fast.  But rendering with raw RGBA data is extremely slow.

I am putting the raw data in a Uint8Array() and using the gl.texImage2D() that accepts width height, while the PNG rendering uses the gl.texImage2D() version that accepts an Image and no width height.

I would have assumed the raw data would be faster since it doesn't have to load and decode the png file, but it seems backwards.

My background is largely C++ and have a fair amount of experience with desktop OpenGL.  HTML5 and javascript are still fairly new to me.

Why is WebGL rendering the Image() (1024x1024) much much quicker, and even a small image of raw data (32x32) much much slower?  Is there a way to speed this up?  I am running this on the newest version of Firefox.

Edit:
The problem was actually passing data from the plugin to javascript.  I was profiling using Date.getTime(), but apparently that is not a good way since the time before and after creating an array and getting data from the plugin was the same.  I've switched to getting data from a local HTTP server which has shown great performance improvement when getting and rendering raw data.

Comment: Have you profiled this, to make sure its the actual `texImage2D` call thats slow?

Comment: Could you please show your test code, so we can look it over for inefficiencies?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, let's test

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
var work = document.getElementById("w");
var fps = document.getElementById("f");

var imageData = new Uint8Array(canvas.width * canvas.height * 4);

var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(
    gl, ["vshader", "fshader"], ["a_position"]);
gl.useProgram(program);

var verts = [
      1,  1,  
     -1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1, -1,  
];
var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

var tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

var adjust = 1;
var workAmount = adjust;
var oneFrame = 1 / 50;  // shoot for 50fps since timing is poor
var then = Date.now() * 0.001;
var frameCount = 0;
var maxIndex = canvas.width * canvas.height;

function doStuff() {
    var now = Date.now() * 0.001;
    var deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;
    ++frameCount;
    
    if (deltaTime < oneFrame) {
        workAmount += adjust;
    } else {
        workAmount = Math.max(workAmount - adjust, adjust);
    }
    
    fps.innerHTML = (1 / deltaTime).toFixed(1);
    work.innerHTML = workAmount;
    
    var color = (frameCount & 1) ? 255 : 128;
    for (var i = 0; i < workAmount; ++i) {
        var index = (Math.random() * maxIndex | 0) * 4;
        imageData[index + 0] = color;
        imageData[index + 1] = color;
        imageData[index + 2] = color;
        imageData[index + 3] = 255;
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 
                     gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);    
    }
    
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    requestAnimationFrame(doStuff);
}
doStuff();
```

```css
body, document {
    font-family: monospace;
}
#c {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#outer {
  position: relative;   
}
#info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <canvas id="c" width="1024" height="1024"></canvas>
    <div id="info">
      <div>fps : <span id="f"></span></div>
      <div>work: <span id="w"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script id="vshader" type="whatever">
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    varying vec2 v_texcoord;

    void main() {
      gl_Position = a_position;
      v_texcoord = a_position.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
    }    
</script>
<script id="fshader" type="whatever">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler, v_texcoord);
}
</script>
```

On my 2014 MBP I get about 20 1024x1024 RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE uploads a frame at 50fps on Chrome and about the same on Firefox

What do you get? Are you sure your bottleneck is the texture uploads and not something else?

Comment: Your test code was quick, I found the bottleneck was actually in passing data from our plugin to javascript.  My original timings used the js object Date.getTime(), but the time value is the same before and after getting the data (using new Uint8Array(plugin().getData()) so that through me off.  Apparently I'm missing something about how the Date object is working.

Comment: Very very cool you are so helpful @gman thank you this solutionh was a good read

Answer (score 0):

The slowness could come from (at least) 3 things:

1. WebGL has to do error checking with texImage2D. Perhaps the browsers knows that data from a Image is always valid and thus skip this check.
2. WebGL may need to do data conversion behind the hood; For example, If you use premultiplied alpha; then WebGL may need to do the conversion with raw data; whereas Image element is already in premultiplied alpha (most likely).
3. Browsers are still godly slow at creating TypeArrays. If you are creating a new TypeArray every frame that will slow down performance.